# Oracle SQL exclude rows when columns are empty

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this Oracle SQL query which selects several columns containing values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     name,
     age,
     weight,
     height
FROM
    my_table
```

I want to exclude rows from the report that contain no values but they should be reported if they have 0.00 as a value.

**EDIT:** I add another case that I missed, the rows should be only excluded if all of them contain no value. Row d should be in the report.

Example:

| name | age | weight | height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 10 | 20 | 105 |
| b | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| c |  |  |  |
| d |  | 15 | 110 |

After the SQL statement, this should be reported:

| name | age | weight | height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 10 | 20 | 105 |
| b | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| d |  | 15 | 110 |

Comment: SELECT [...] FROM my_table WHERE age IS NOT NULL AND weight IS NOT NULL AND height IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     name,
     age,
     weight,
     height
FROM
    my_table
WHERE LENGTH(age) > 0 or LENGTH(weight) > 0 OR LENGTH(height) > 0
 OR age is not null or weight is not null or height is not null
```

If the data type of the columns is numeric, you can simply check for NULL values only.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     name,
     age,
     weight,
     height
FROM
    my_table
WHERE age is not null or weight is not null or height is not null
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I forgot to add one more example. Rows should be only excluded if all 3 columns contain no values (see my edit).

Comment: @honeymoon yes, I was guessing this :-) that's why we are using `OR` statement in order to return the row if any of the values is not empty/null.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Not Null condition in a where clause,

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     name,
     age,
     weight,
     height
FROM
    my_table
where age is not null and weight is not null and height is not null;
```

You can use 'or' instead of 'and' if you want to see records which has values for any one of the metric and others have blank.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I forgot to add one more example. Rows should be only excluded if all 3 columns contain no values (see my edit)